# Android YouTube API “An error occurred while initializing YouTube player”

Tags: android, android-fragments, video, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I have a Fragment containing a [YouTubePlayerSupportFragment](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerSupportFragment). This fragment is inside a ViewPager.

The player works fine on my Galaxy S3 Android phone (4.3 / API 18) and on my VM (4.3 / API 18).
But on every other phones i've tried, the player shows a `An error occurred while initializing YouTube player` message and throw a [onInitializationFailure](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener#onInitializationFailure(com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider,%20com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult)) with an `UNKNOWN_ERROR` reason.

I've checked the LogCat and there is absolutly no other error/warning, from my app or from youtube.

It didnt work on the following devices:

- Android 4.2.1 - Youtube 10.18.55
- Android 4.4.2 - Youtube 10.18.55
- Android 5.1 - Youtube above requirement

I have absolutely no idea why it worked on some and why it didn't on others.

Here is the code of the Fragment:

```
    public class RoomFragmentVideo extends PlugFragment implements
    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener, YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener {
            private static String CLASS_DBG_NAME = "RoomFragmentVideo";

            private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;

            private YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayer ;
            private int playerInitialized;
            private YouTubePlayer player;

            static PlugFragment init(Bundle args) {
                     RoomFragmentVideo roomFrag = new RoomFragmentVideo();
                     // Supply val input as an argument.
                     roomFrag.setArguments(args);
                     Log.d(Constants.APP_DBG_LOG + CLASS_DBG_NAME + " - ","Created with args Room: "  + ((String)args.get(RoomFragmentChat.ARG_ROOM)));
                     return roomFrag;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             thisActivity = (AppCompatActivity) this.getActivity();
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                     View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_roomvideo, container,false);
                     youTubePlayer = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
                     FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                     transaction.add(R.id.youtube_fragment, youTubePlayer).commit();
                     youTubePlayer.initialize(YouTubeDeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
                     return rootview;

            }

            protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
                return youTubePlayer;
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
                  getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(YouTubeDeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
                }
            }         

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                          YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
                    if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
                          errorReason.getErrorDialog(this.getActivity(), 1).show();
                          Log.e(Constants.APP_DBG_LOG + CLASS_DBG_NAME + " - YouTube" ,"[Recoverable] Reason : " + errorReason.toString());
                    }
                    else {
                            //String errorMessage = String.format(getString(R.string.error_player), errorReason.toString());
                            String errorMessage = "Video couldnt load";
                            Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.e(Constants.APP_DBG_LOG + CLASS_DBG_NAME + " - YouTube" ,"[Unrecoverable] Reason : " + errorReason.toString() + " Message: " + errorMessage);
                            playerInitialized = -1; 
                    }

            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
                          boolean wasRestored) {
                            this.player = player;
                            player.setPlayerStyle(PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
                            player.loadVideo(this.videoID);
                            playerInitialized = 1;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPause(){
                    super.onPause();
                    Log.v(Constants.APP_DBG_LOG + CLASS_DBG_NAME + " - " , "onPause");
            }

            @Override
            public void onResume(){
                    super.onResume();
                    Log.v(Constants.APP_DBG_LOG + CLASS_DBG_NAME + " - " , "onResume");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStop(){
                    super.onStop();
                    player = null;
                    playerInitialized = -2;
                    Log.v(Constants.APP_DBG_LOG + CLASS_DBG_NAME + " - " , "onStop");
            }

            @Override
            public void setUserVisibleHint (boolean isVisibleToUser){
                    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
                    if(isVisibleToUser){
                            this.resume();
                    }
                    Log.v(Constants.APP_DBG_LOG + CLASS_DBG_NAME + " - " , "setUserVisibleHint, status: " + isVisibleToUser);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdStarted() {
                    return;                
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(ErrorReason arg0) {
                    Log.e(Constants.APP_DBG_LOG + CLASS_DBG_NAME + " - " +"YoutubePlayer", arg0.name());
                    Toast.makeText(thisActivity, "YoutubePlayer error: " + arg0.name(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoaded(String arg0) {
                    return;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoading() {
                    return;
            }

            @Override
            public void onVideoEnded() {
                    return;
            }

            @Override
            public void onVideoStarted() {
                    return;

            }
    }
```

And here is the XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

       <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I'm still blocked by this error, i noticed that it only happen on release version apk and not when using the Eclipse debug/run buttons.
I thought it was the key so i changed it and tried the new one on the YouTube API exemple project and it worked fine... but it's still not working on my app. I'm really lost ... 
I'd really appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in fact proguard. 
Here is what i added to the `proguard-project.txt` file:

```
# keep youtube / google
-keep class com.google.api.services.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.youtube.player.** { *; }
# Needed by google-api-client to keep generic types and @Key annotations accessed via reflection
-keepclassmembers class * {
  @com.google.api.client.util.Key <fields>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```
-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
   public *;
}
```