# Didn't find class "com.google.android.youtube.api.jar.client.RemoteEmbeddedPlayer"

Tags: android, android-studio, youtube-data-api

[image]I am trying to play Youtube video in my app but failed with error on screen "An error occured while initializing the YouTube player"

I have used SHA-1 key to generate API key, which has been genrated sucessfully i think and not sure if error is coming due to this, please help me to resolve.

Activity Code -:

```
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    public static final String API_KEY = "my API KEY";

    public static final String VIDEO_ID = "1M2gC86Q_9o";

   // public static final String VIDEO_ID = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1M2gC86Q_9o";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        /** Initializing YouTube player view **/
        YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_player);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failured to Initialize!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        /** add listeners to YouTubePlayer instance **/
        player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
        player.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);

        /** Start buffering **/
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
        }
    }

    private PlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener = new PlaybackEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPaused() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlaying() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopped() {
        }

    };

    private PlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener = new PlayerStateChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAdStarted() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(ErrorReason arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaded(String arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoading() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoEnded() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoStarted() {
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void setSupportActionBar(Toolbar supportActionBar) {
        //this.supportActionBar = supportActionBar;
    }
}
```

Error Headlines are -:

```
com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w$a: Unable to find dynamic class com.google.android.youtube.api.jar.client.RemoteEmbeddedPlayer
                                                                                                 at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source)....



Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.youtube.api.jar.client.RemoteEmbeddedPlayer" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/app/YouTube_l1_64/YouTube_l1_64.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/app/YouTube_l1_64/lib/arm, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]



Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Zip archive '/system/app/YouTube_l1_64/YouTube_l1_64.apk' doesn't contain classes.dex (error msg: Entry not found)
```

Buil.Gradle (Module:App)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.administrator.youtube"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}
```

Comment: post your `build.gradle` .  Error is `ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: I have uploaded the build.gradle, i am using  youtubeandroidplayerapi.jar

Comment: `youtubeandroidplayerapi.jar` not showing in your `dependencies` section .Properly import

Comment: I never used it from the google play services, so Im used to use `YouTube Android Player API` https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/ Download the jar and add to your gradle then let me know if it works.

Comment: @Akash I take a look in maven and checked they have a newest version, replace the `:v3-rev120-1.19.0` to `:v3-rev157-1.21.0` then rebuild your project.

Comment: Yes, its right, but you've added one more `:`, replace for this 
`compile  "com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev157-1.21.0"`  and remove `compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')`

Comment: same problem continues... could not find what to do

Comment: The reason is because it can not find this class `RemoteEmbeddedPlayer` within the library, possibly why it is outdated, or you library is not compiling, if it cannot solve your problem, start a bound or wait for more answers and update your gradle file keeping this library, i will implement it then i answer you later.

Comment: the code Unable to find dynamic class com.google.android.youtube.api.jar.client.RemoteEmbeddedPlayer, as i have tried with .jar too

Comment: if my lib is not compiling then how required file is being imported in my mainAtivity class

Comment: @diogojme please find complete code on given link -:   https://www.dropbox.com/sh/u0jct82twta9bjz/AAB-wfn5jKsgFIM04xf66Eira?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gradle uri `google-api-services-youtube` was wrong, replace your `gradle` dependences for this:

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
   compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev157-1.21.0'
}
```

I found [here](https://www.versioneye.com/java/com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube/v3-rev120-1.19.0). Then I just replaced for the latest version `v3-rev157-1.21.0`

and it will work:

[image]

Comment: i have android 5.1 as like your screen pic,  but still it is not playing video on my mobile. If you can please change the screen shot with this video id https://youtu.be/RhxNLk3WfmY, above was randomly picked.

Comment: I have added the image for the video ID you sent above and tried this one too and works `public static final String VIDEO_ID = "-J7J_IWUhls";` Please if it works for you vote my answer as acceptable. Thank you

Comment: so what you think it plays well on your mobile but still not on my mobile, what might be the issue. please suggest

Comment: @Akash add your phone device model in the description too, maybe it is a specific device bug in the youtube api.

Comment: @Akash playing videos with lower internet could give this error too. Sometimes I use youtube in an 3g and it gave's me this error. Please try to change for wi-fi network.

Comment: @Akash installing the youtube app make it work? I have to know for update my answer

Comment: still video is not running via my app while well playing in opera browswer, if  you have found any other mistake in my code, please provid me or you have used different api key, i dont think but might be api key may be responsible.

Comment: No, i didn't changed anything in your code, only the gradle file.I will keep trying to reproduce in my phone. But you are still getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` ?

Comment: yes Please check the Project Link and find the new file added named Complete Error.txt, please open it in notepad++ or any other editor for clear view ( https://www.dropbox.com/s/80934m0069saqky/Complete%20Error.txt?dl=0 )

Comment: I found this answer accepted for the same error, please can you test it? I can't reproduce this error. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32424164/1879661. And please, make sure you clean and build your project again.

Comment: ok, no matter and first of all thanks for your Time,  if  you can please resolve this query, this is camera related  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177582/why-image-is-being-saved-in-landscape-mode?noredirect=1#comment56365674_34177582

Comment: Ok, I will keep looking, i will check the another question.

Comment: there is proguard-rules.pro file in my proj while implented the suggested link and failed again, tommorow i will test my app on other mobile too

Comment: Have you received the Complete Error.txt file in my project link??

Comment: Welcome the latest version so far: `com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev183-1.23.0`